# angular2 SimpleChange is not storing `previousValue`

Tags: angular

this is a follow-up to: [ngOnChange not storing previousValue property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38317945/ngonchange-not-storing-previousvalue-property)

I'm using `ionic2`/`angular2` with this component: https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar and the following markup

```
<ion-card  class="timer"
  *ngFor="let snapshot of timers | toJSON"
> 
  <ion-card-content>
    <round-progress 
      [current]="snapshot.remaining" 
      [max]="snapshot.duration"
      [rounded]="true"
      [responsive]="true"
      [duration]="18"
      >
    </round-progress>
</ion-card>
```

using ChromeDevTools, I see the following in `SimpleChange.current`:

```
  /** Change detection callback. */
  ngOnChanges(changes): void {
    if (changes.current) {
      this._animateChange(changes.current.previousValue, changes.current.currentValue);
    } else {
      this._setPath(this.current);
    }
  }
// changes.current.previousValue = {}
// changes.current.cureentValue = 123 // int
// changes.current.isFirstChange() = true
```

Why am I not storing `changes.current.previousValue` correctly?

the `toJSON` pipe calls this method, which returns an anonymous object:

```
  /**
   * create a snapshot of the timer
   */
  toJSON() : TimerAttributes {
    const remaining = this.check(true);
    console.log(this.id, this.duration, remaining)
    return {
      id: this.id,
      label: this.label,
      // asMilliseconds
      duration: this.duration,
      // asMilliseconds
      remaining: remaining,
      humanize: this.humanize(remaining),
      // as Unixtime
      expires: this.expires
    }
  }
```

my only guess is that I'm returning a different object for `snapshot` on each change detection loop, so I lose `previousValue`. But if so, what is the easy fix?

Comment: my guess is correct. If I use `Object.assign(snapshot, o.toJSON())`, then `snapshot` references the *same* object and `SimpleChange.previousValue` is correctly saves the previousValue for `snapshot.remaining`. BUT, then I am at risk of getting an `Expression has changed after it was checked` error.  What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleChange` does not store the correct value for `previousValue` if the 
object of the `@Input` variable changes.

```
  /**
   * create a snapshot of the timer, return as anonymous object
   */
  toJSON() : TimerAttributes {
    const remaining = this.check();
    // console.log(this.id, this.duration, remaining)
    return {
      id: this.id,
      label: this.label,
      // asMilliseconds
      duration: this.duration,
      // asMilliseconds
      remaining: remaining,
      humanize: this.humanize(remaining),
      // as Unixtime
      expires: this.expires
    }
  }


  /**
   * return the SAME object with updated attr value 
   */
  snap(): TimerAttributes {
    Object.assign( this.snapshot, this.toJSON())
    return this.snapshot;
  }
```

If my `toJSONPipe` calls `o.toJSON()` I get an **anonymous** object with attribute values and `SimpleChange` does not store `changes.current.previousValue`.

If my `toJSONPipe` calls `o.snap()` I get the **SAME attribute** `o.snapshot` with updated attribute values and `SimpleChange` correctly stores `changes.current.previousValue`.